# When to use class-based component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class

After [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) were introduced in React 16.8 with all the new ways to control component's state and lifecycle methods in a functional component such as `useState` and `useEffect`, the remaining difference between a functional component and a class-based component isn't obvious anymore, so what's the real difference ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-with-hooks-that-i-couldnt-with-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some lifecycle methods, which can't be emulated with React Hooks(e.g. [componentDidCatch()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch)).

In this cases you still need class components, but overall, you don't need them, and it's already totally fine, if you have an app without them.